# Can a trigger create a TABLE when inserting data?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-10

I have a trigger that keeps track of history of table `dev` by inserting a row in table `dev_hist`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_dev_hist() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $dev_hist$
    DECLARE action_name text;
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
            OLD.timestamp := current_timestamp;
            action_name := 'deleted';
            INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name, user, OLD.*;
        ELSE
            NEW.timestamp := current_timestamp;
            IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                action_name := 'added';
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                action_name := 'modified';
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name, user, NEW.*;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$dev_hist$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dev_hist ON dev;
CREATE TRIGGER dev_hist AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON dev
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_dev_hist();
```

Problem is, if table `dev_hist` doesn't exist, it throws error.

Is it possible to change it, so it would create table if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Why don't you just create the table at the same time as you create the trigger?

Comment: To me the question is: why `dev_hist` doesn't exists? If this trigger is part of an update you should ensure this table is created at the same time.

Comment: The answer to the question however is: yes, a trigger can create a table

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ - The requirements keep changing, and every time I have to recreate the tables, etc... so I have to make the same change in two places - `CREATE dev...` and `CREATE dev_hist...`

Comment: I wonder what kind of problems (errors, deadlocks, etc) you can get if you have 2 or more overlapping transactions, both trying to insert and thus both trying to create the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This is similar to McNets's solution, with the addition of adding all the `dev`'s fields:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION verify() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $verify$
    DECLARE action_name text;
    DECLARE rec record;
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
            OLD.timestamp := current_timestamp;
            action_name := 'deleted';
            --INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name, user, OLD.*;
            rec := OLD;
        ELSE
            NEW.timestamp := current_timestamp;
            IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                action_name := 'added';
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                action_name := 'modified';
            END IF;
            --INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name, user, NEW.*;
            rec := NEW;
        END IF;

        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
                      FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                      WHERE  table_name = 'dev_hist') THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'creating table';
            CREATE TABLE dev_hist AS
                SELECT action_name, user, rec.*;
        ELSE
            RAISE NOTICE 'table exists';
            INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name, user, rec.*;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$verify$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I declared a new variable `rec` and then instead of inserting, I copy either `NEW` or `OLD` to rec.

Then at the end, I check if table exists, and then I do either `CREATE TABLE dev_hist AS SELECT...` or `INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT`

I ran a few consecutive inserts, and it prints:

```
NOTICE:  creating table
NOTICE:  table exists
NOTICE:  table exists
NOTICE:  table exists
NOTICE:  table exists
NOTICE:  table exists
INSERT 0 1

Query returned successfully in 69 msec.
```

Comment: Another thought: instead of checking that for each and every insert to the table, you could create a DDL trigger and create the _dev table when the regular table is created.

Comment: Could you point me to the manual?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-EVENT-TRIGGER

Comment: Thanks! This is an awesome idea. That DDL trigger can also add "timestamp" column (if it doesn't exist) and create table triggers, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to check if `dev_hist` table exists, if not you can create it in your trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE T (id int, name text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_dev_hist() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $dev_hist$
    DECLARE action_name text;
    BEGIN

        -- add your catalog information.
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev_hist
        (
            action text
        );

        IF TG_OP = 'DELETE' THEN
            action_name := 'deleted';
            INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name;
        ELSE
            IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
                action_name := 'added';
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
                action_name := 'modified';
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO dev_hist SELECT action_name;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$dev_hist$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS dev_hist ON T;
CREATE TRIGGER dev_hist AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON T
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_dev_hist();
```

> ```
> INSERT INTO T VALUES (1);
> DELETE FROM T WHERE id = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
>
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dev_hist;
> ```
>
> ```
> | action  |
> | :------ |
> | added   |
> | deleted |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6d86db34a8dfd3a0a7cf1a1b86a0b8cf)*

Comment: Thanks, but my trigger also inserts the row that is being inserted, deleted, or updated. So the `dev_hist` table needs to have also all the `dev`'s fields.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know your table schema, so I can't reproduce it. This is an example on how to do it, add as many fields as you need.

Comment: You can create table if not exists by syntax [CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) dev_hist ...